# List of AngularDart directives?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Is the complete list of AngularDart directives documented somewhere?  I understand that this list is subject to change, given the rapid evolution in AngularDart.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is what I have found:

- The classes implementing the directives are listed in the [**angular.directive library** API documentation page](http://ci.angularjs.org/view/Dart/job/angular.dart-master/javadoc/angular.directive.html).
- The list of *event directives* can be found in the [**angular.directive/NgEventDirective**](http://ci.angularjs.org/view/Dart/job/angular.dart-master/javadoc/angular.directive/NgEventDirective.html) class Dartdoc.

Here is the **list of (non-event) directives** extracted from the source as of 2014-02-02:

```
[ng-attr-*]              [ng-model][ng-required]
[ng-bind-html]           [ng-model][pattern]
[ng-bind-template]       [ng-model][required]
[ng-bind]                [ng-multiple]
[ng-checked]             [ng-non-bindable]
[ng-class-even]          [ng-open]
[ng-class-odd]           [ng-pluralize]
[ng-class]               [ng-readonly]
[ng-cloak]               [ng-repeat]
[ng-disabled]            [ng-required]
[ng-form]                [ng-selected]
[ng-hide]                [ng-shallow-repeat]
[ng-href]                [ng-show]
[ng-if]                  [ng-src]
[ng-include]             [ng-srcset]
[ng-model]               [ng-style]
[ng-model][maxlength]    [ng-switch-default]
[ng-model][minlength]    [ng-switch-when]
[ng-model][ng-maxlength] [ng-switch]
[ng-model][ng-minlength] [ng-unless]
[ng-model][ng-pattern]
```

And here is the list of **event directives**:

```
[ng-abort]              [ng-keyup]
[ng-beforecopy]         [ng-load]
[ng-beforecut]          [ng-mousedown]
[ng-beforepaste]        [ng-mouseenter]
[ng-blur]               [ng-mouseleave]
[ng-change]             [ng-mousemove]
[ng-click]              [ng-mouseout]
[ng-contextmenu]        [ng-mouseover]
[ng-copy]               [ng-mouseup]
[ng-cut]                [ng-mousewheel]
[ng-doubleclick]        [ng-paste]
[ng-drag]               [ng-reset]
[ng-dragend]            [ng-scroll]
[ng-dragenter]          [ng-search]
[ng-dragleave]          [ng-select]
[ng-dragover]           [ng-selectstart]
[ng-dragstart]          [ng-speechchange]
[ng-drop]               [ng-submit]
[ng-error]              [ng-toucheancel]
[ng-focus]              [ng-touchend]
[ng-fullscreenchange]   [ng-touchenter]
[ng-fullscreenerror]    [ng-touchleave]
[ng-input]              [ng-touchmove]
[ng-invalid]            [ng-touchstart]
[ng-keydown]            [ng-transitionend]
[ng-keypress]
```

I am working on a better list and will post back as soon as it is available.