# Dynamic src field in image creates 404 with dart2js and cancelled GET in dartium

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have a component with the following HTML code:

```dart
<div class="media productCard" ng-click="prod.handleClick()">
    <img class="media__img" 
         src="{{prod.getStatusImageUrl()}}"
         title="{{prod.getStatusText()}}" />
    <div class="media__body">
        <h3>{{prod.product.name}}</h3>
        <p>{{prod.getBrand()}}</p>
        <p>{{prod.product.notes}}</p>
        <p>source: {{prod.product.source}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The src field is triggered and the browser will fire a request for "/prod.getStatusImageUrl()" and I will get a 404 error.  I want to evaluate the src field before the browser creates the GET request.

Note that Dartium will cancel this GET request, but standard JS browsers will complete the request and result in a 404.  However, the image is rendered correctly in the end, since the all browsers appear to create a second request, I presume once angulardart has done its magic.

I have tried ng-cloak, but this does not help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databinding for the `src` attribute doesn't work because the browser immediately starts loading the '{{something}}` 'URL'.

Angular provides `ng-src="{{something}}" as a workaround.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc
[List of AngularDart directives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21516297/list-of-angulardart-directives)